# rsocket - how to balance the load

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java

rsocket seems to be a cool idea. I have this question and I could not find a better answer.

Lets consider this initial set up. client sends multiple requests to the server-1 sequentially.

```
client --> server-1
```

server-1 is doing some compute intensive tasks. So auto-scaler created another instance of server which is server-2 after some time. Now the setup became like this.

```
client --> server-1
           server-2
```

As per my understanding client-->server-1 connection is established and kept alive. We use this connection for all the client-server communication. How to make use of another server - server-2 to share some of the client requests like this.

```
client --> server-1
   |-----> server-2
```

Otherwise it will be a sequential processing.

I use spring boot with rsocket.

Comment: Good answer on load balancing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254112/correct-usage-of-loadbalancersocketclient-with-springs-rsocketrequester/65268468#65268468

Answer (score 3):

There are two options for this:

- use low-level load balancer on client side from [rsocket-load-balancer](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:rsocket-load-balancer)
- deploy RSocket broker between client and server, some options are [Netifi Broker](https://www.netifi.com/netifi-ce) or [Alibaba RSocket Broker](https://github.com/alibaba/alibaba-rsocket-broker)